# Any tips on modeling this mushroom?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

I'm not quite sure the approach for this and would be grateful for any tips. Using cycles in 2.81

[image]

Comment: just curious, what's the name of the fungus?

Answer (score 1):

Create hair particle system. Add wind pointing down. Add material.

Comment: Ok great, I'll give that a shot. Thank you very much.